# Extract dataframe from inside dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to generate a dataframe basic from a dataframe which contains inside another dataframe and a list

Sample file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfdM-GVuYz7q5Nk_KktUabrWqlpDMFt1/view?usp=sharing

Code starts reading a json with jsonlite stream_in and generating **result** object.

**result** is dataframe containig a sub dataframe ball which contains a list xyz and a column speed

```r
# result (dataframe)
#  |
#  |
#  ball (dataframe) contains xyz list and speed numeric so
#    |
#    |
#   xyz (list) elements
#         [[1]]
#          [1] -0.08  0.17  0.00
#
#   speed (numeric column)
```

My requirement is to get a dataframe with below listed columns and WITHOUT homePlayers and awayPlayers lists.

- period --> direct from result
- frameIdx  --> direct from result
- gameClock  --> direct from result
- xyz   --> extract it from **ball sub dataframe and list**
- speed --> extract it from **ball sub dataframe**
- live  --> direct from result
- lastTouch --> direct from result

required df columns period,frameIdx, gameClock , x,y,z,speed   ,live,lastTouch

My main problem is extracting ball contents in columns

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
library(dplyr)      # for %>% and other dplyr functions

file_match_json <- 'match.jsonl'

result <- as_tibble(jsonlite::stream_in(file(file_match_json)))
```

Here it is the result object type with this underlying structure

```r
> result
# A tibble: 30 x 8
   period frameIdx gameClock homePlayers       awayPlayers       ball$xyz  $speed live  lastTouch
    <int>    <int>     <dbl> <list>            <list>            <list>     <dbl> <lgl> <chr>    
 1      1        0      0    <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.6 FALSE home     
 2      1        1      0.04 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 3      1        2      0.08 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 4      1        3      0.12 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 5      1        4      0.16 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.7 TRUE  home     
 6      1        5      0.2  <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.5 TRUE  home     
 7      1        6      0.24 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.3 TRUE  home     
 8      1        7      0.28 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.0 TRUE  home     
 9      1        8      0.32 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   11.8 TRUE  home     
10      1        9      0.36 <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]> <dbl [3]>   11.5 TRUE  home     


# below it is the structure of the sub dataframe inside result
str(result$ball)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ xyz  :List of 30
  ..$ : num  -0.08 0.17 0
  ..$ : num  -0.18 0.16 0
  ..$ : num  -0.46 0.16 0
  ...
 $ speed: num  12.6 12.8 12.8 12.8 12.7 ...

# Tried this with no luck because i need to unnest/unlist xyz
df <- result %>%
  select(period,frameIdx,gameClock,live,lastTouch,ball$xyz, ball$speed)
```

Comment: Your link isn't working for me :( but perhaps `hoist()` from `library(tidyr)` is what you are looking for? https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html

Comment: I will try hoist , here it is the updated link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfdM-GVuYz7q5Nk_KktUabrWqlpDMFt1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix for this would be to add a flatten argument like so: `stream_in(path, flatten = T)`

More thoroughly:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(janitor)

path <- file("match.jsonl")

result <- stream_in(path, flatten = T) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  clean_names()

result
#> # A tibble: 30 x 9
#>    period frame_idx game_clock home_players away_players live  last_touch
#>     <int>     <int>      <dbl> <list>       <list>       <lgl> <chr>     
#>  1      1         0       0    <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ FALSE home      
#>  2      1         1       0.04 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  3      1         2       0.08 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  4      1         3       0.12 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  5      1         4       0.16 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  6      1         5       0.2  <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  7      1         6       0.24 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  8      1         7       0.28 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#>  9      1         8       0.32 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#> 10      1         9       0.36 <df[,3] [11~ <df[,3] [11~ TRUE  home      
#> # ... with 20 more rows, and 2 more variables: ball_xyz <list>,
#> #   ball_speed <dbl>
```

Note that `ball_xyz` and `ball_speed` have been split or flattened depending on how you look at it.

We get your desired `select()` statement as such:

```r
result %>%
  select(period, frame_idx, game_clock, live, last_touch, ball_xyz, ball_speed)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 7
#>    period frame_idx game_clock live  last_touch ball_xyz  ball_speed
#>     <int>     <int>      <dbl> <lgl> <chr>      <list>         <dbl>
#>  1      1         0       0    FALSE home       <dbl [3]>       12.6
#>  2      1         1       0.04 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.8
#>  3      1         2       0.08 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.8
#>  4      1         3       0.12 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.8
#>  5      1         4       0.16 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.7
#>  6      1         5       0.2  TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.5
#>  7      1         6       0.24 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.3
#>  8      1         7       0.28 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       12.0
#>  9      1         8       0.32 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       11.8
#> 10      1         9       0.36 TRUE  home       <dbl [3]>       11.5
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Taking things a bit further, we can use `unnest_wider()` to expand the `ball_xyz` values into their own columns.

```r
result %>%
  select(period, frame_idx, game_clock, live, last_touch, ball = ball_xyz, ball_speed) %>%
  mutate(ball = map(ball, ~ setNames(.x, c("x", "y", "z")))) %>%
  unnest_wider(ball, names_sep = "_", simplify = T)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 9
#>    period frame_idx game_clock live  last_touch ball_x ball_y ball_z
#>     <int>     <int>      <dbl> <lgl> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1      1         0       0    FALSE home        -0.08   0.17      0
#>  2      1         1       0.04 TRUE  home        -0.18   0.16      0
#>  3      1         2       0.08 TRUE  home        -0.46   0.16      0
#>  4      1         3       0.12 TRUE  home        -0.89   0.16      0
#>  5      1         4       0.16 TRUE  home        -1.3    0.16      0
#>  6      1         5       0.2  TRUE  home        -1.78   0.16      0
#>  7      1         6       0.24 TRUE  home        -2.29   0.17      0
#>  8      1         7       0.28 TRUE  home        -2.82   0.17      0
#>  9      1         8       0.32 TRUE  home        -3.36   0.18      0
#> 10      1         9       0.36 TRUE  home        -3.91   0.2       0
#> # ... with 20 more rows, and 1 more variable: ball_speed <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks. First reading file flatten and then using unnest wider.